# cannot add exchange mail on Nexus S running 4.1.2

Tags: email

I am not able to add an exchange email account to my Nexus S.  When I select the add account, corporate, and put in email and password i get to next page with the ssl option and press next, I get error message that it couldn't open connection to server.

This is a new account for me, but it works just fine on my WIN 7 laptop, so this is clearly an issue with Android.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you know what kind of SSL (Port) it requires?

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue of login name and server name.

After entering your email address and password. **Don't** click next, but click **Manual Setup**.

The next page should ask for your username, password(properly fill in for you already), and Exchange server.

```
Username: <Windows Domain>\<Windows Login>
Exchange Server: (you should know, or find out from your Outlook setting)
```

Good luck!